# Upper bound for Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis

We have $\xi$ a real-valued integrable function and want to show: $$\left|\frac{e^{ih\xi}-1}{h}\right|\leq|\xi|.$$

My attempt: Using

$$e^{ih\xi}=\cos(h\xi)+i\sin(h\xi)$$
$$\cos(x)\leq1,\ |\sin(x)|\leq|x|\ \forall x$$

We have:

$$\left|\frac{e^{ih\xi}-1}{h}\right|\leq\left|\frac{1-1}{h}+i\frac{\sin(h\xi)}{h}\right|\leq|\xi|.$$

While I'm confident this is a valid argument, it didn't feel very intuitive. Is this the only way to show this inequality?

Comment: $\Big|\int^x_0 e^{it}\,dt\Big|\leq \int^x_0|e^{it}|\,dt$